# How can a class have no constructor?

Tags: c#, .net, constructor, clr

A while back I asked about instantiating a HttpContext object. Now that I have learnt what I didn't know, what confuses me is that you cannot say HttpContext ctx = new HttpContext(); because the object does not have a constructor.

But doesn't every class need a constructor? In C#, if you don't provide one, the compiler automatically provides a default cstr for you.

Also, if I have a string (example: "Hello There!") and I say Convert.ToBoolean("Hello"), or any string, how does this work? What happens behind the scenes? I guess a book like CLR Via C# would be handy in this case.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 24):

Constructor can be private or protected.
Also you can't create instance of abstract class, even if that class has public constructor.

Comment: Or internal; or protected internal

Answer (score 7):

HttpContext has a public constructor with two overloads but it's not the default (no params) one.

As an example, you need to pass in a SimpleWorkerRequest instance in order to instatiate an HttpContext instance and assign it to HttpContext.Current:

```
//Initialize this stuff with some crap
string appVirtualDir = "/"; 
string appPhysicalDir = @"C:\Documents and Settings\"; 
string page = @"localhost"; 
string query = string.Empty; 
TextWriter output = null;    
//Create a SimpleWorkerRequest object passing down the crap
SimpleWorkerRequest workerRequest = new SimpleWorkerRequest(appVirtualDir, appPhysicalDir, page, query, output);
//Create your fake HttpContext instance 
HttpContext.Current = new HttpContext(workerRequest);
```

See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.httpcontext.aspx) for details.

Anyway some classes don't have public constructors - think of a [singleton](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternSingleton.aspx) class for example, constructor is private (and you can call the static getInstance method to get current instance or create it if it is null).

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

Singletons, for example, do not have constructors, or at least, no public constructors. So if your class is a singleton, instead of writing

```
MyClass c = new MyClass();
```

You would write instead

```
MyClass c = MyClass.getInstance();
```

Comment: singletons constructors should be made private

Comment: Singletons do have constructors, but it should only be called once.

Comment: not only should they be made private, they have to be made private or they no longer are guaranteed to function properly as singletons

Answer (score 3):

You have 3 questions there...

**HttpContext**; it actually has two public constructors - but in reality you aren't expected to use them. In more general terms, you can use non-default constructors like so: `MyType foo = new MyType("abc");`.

**Missing constructor**
Fairly well covered already, but no: `abstract` / `static` are the simplest, but it also isn't necessary to have a *public* constructor.

**ToBoolean**
Behing the scenes, this will do the moral equivalent of `bool.Parse("Hello")`, which simply checks for known strings - in particular "True" and "False" (using OrdinalIgnoreCase, having dealt with null/trimming/etc).

Answer (score 2):

In one word : [static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx(VS.80).aspx).

Otherwise, a class might be instantiated internally or privately (Factory or Singleton)

Signleton :

```
Class A{
public static readonly A Instance = new A();

private A()
{
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the HttpContext constructor has been marked private. That means that you cannot instantiate it yourself. The .net framework creates one for you behind the scenes...

Comment: Actually, there are 2 public ctors for HttpContext

Comment: sure - they take SimpleWorkerRequest or HttpRequest, HttpResponse

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Singleton Design Pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternSingleton.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you make the constructor private, you cannot extarnaly instatiate a class. But within the class it is possible. So you can provide a static method that returns a instance of the class. The singleton pattern is based on this.

Answer (score -1):

Compiler does not create 
default constructor of a class until the class has constructor with arguments.
In HttpContext class , it has 2 constructors with arguments . So, error is shown when you do HttpContext obj = new HttpContext().

```
public class Sample
{
    int x;
    public Sample (int x)
    {
        x = 2;
    }
}
public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Sample s = new Sample();//error is shown
        }
    }
```

When you remove The above constructor of Sample class , there will be no error because compiler creates default constructor (constructor with no arguments).

Comment: `HttpContext` doesn't have *any* acceptable constructor, with any arguments, not just a parameterless constructor.

Comment: You haven't fixed the problems with your answer.

Comment: Oh ok but is my ans logically correct or i have misinterpreted? @Servy

Comment: You have in no way answered the question.  Just look at the documentation for yourself to see what constructors `HttpClient` has.